# Select specific files from GitLab repository to new release

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to create a release for my repository inside GitLab, but honestly it "zips up" whole branch of my repository.

Is there possibility to do this f.e. only for `bin/Debug` or even only for specified files/folder, where the `exe` files are built?

I'm trying to achieve that with the C# .Net project.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually create a new branch, clean it from what you don't want to be in the release. - create a tag base on that branch, and create a release from that tag.

Make a POST request to the GitLab API endpoint for creating a release (/projects/:id/releases), where :id is the ID or URL-encoded path of your project.
Include the necessary parameters such as the release tag, name, and description in the request body.